# Triggering a soft reset (Arduino Leonardo)

Tags: timers, arduino-leonardo, reset

I want to trigger a soft reset on my Arduino Leonardo, and after some searching settled on using the watchdog timer, as it seemed to be the easiest and cleanest way to do it.

However, I don't think it works as it should. It seems to work fine on the following example:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

int outputPin = LED_BUILTIN;

void setup() {
  MCUSR = 0;
  wdt_disable();
  pinMode(outputPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(outputPin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(outputPin, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(outputPin, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(outputPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  wdt_enable(WDTO_15MS);
  while (true) {}
}
```

The LED blinks continuously,.

But for the following example:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

void setup() {
  MCUSR = 0;
  wdt_disable();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("Hello");
}

void loop() {
  wdt_enable(WDTO_15MS);
  while (true) {}
}
```

"Hello" only gets printed once (where I would expect it to arrive continuously).

I tried increasing the watchdog timeout to 2 seconds, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: try for a test a longer time, for example WDTO_2S. some bootloaders don't reset the wdt flag and then the next reset is triggered before the chip enters your setup().

Comment: @Juraj changing `WDTO_15MS` to `WDTO_2S` in the above example only causes the final state (`L` on, `RX` blinking) to set in 2 seconds later, unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: you test with a sketch without Serial like the sketch in the Question?

Comment: Hint: You could define a function to the reset-vector, e.g. `void (*RESET)() = NULL;` and then call the function when wanted, e.g. `RESET();`. Please note that all hardware registers are not reset. The sketch setup should not assume a hardware register state.

Comment: @Juraj I edited the question. I have since discovered that I was missing `pinMode` from my original example, and that solved that specific issue. However, for the (now added) Serial example it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MikaelPatel do you mean something like this? https://pastebin.com/raw/0UNf3mik This still only prints "Hello" once.

Comment: Try the blink led instead. Set registers correctly in the setup.

Comment: Oh hold on, I think the problem might just be that after every reset the serial monitor disconnects (even though it doesn't get greyed out), and that's why I can't see the following "Hello"s. I'll investigate a bit further.

Comment: Serial (USB) will disconnect and the USB connection to the host is dropped. You will need a much more advanced detect and reconnect on the host :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that was the only issue. Thanks for the help MikaelPatel and Juraj!

Comment: one more thing: the ` while (!Serial);` stops the sketch if USB connection is not open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out my code was working correctly, the watchdog performed the reset as it should, the problem was only that I needed to relaunch the serial monitor after each reset.